# LINQ throwing exception when attempting to compare dates

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have the following:

```
return db.Events
            .Where(e => 
                e.BedId == bed 
                && e.Date.Year == date.Year 
                && e.Date.Month == date.Month
                && e.Date.Day == date.Day)
            .Select(x => new EventViewModel() { 
                Id          = x.Id,
                Date        = x.Date.Date.ToString(),
                StartTime   = x.StartTime.ToString(),
                EndTime     = x.EndTime.ToString(),
                Planned     = x.Planned,
                EngineSN    = x.EngineSN,
                Details     = x.Details,
                Bed         = x.Bed.Name,
                Category    = x.Subcategory.Category.Name,
                Subcategory = x.Subcategory.Name,
                Project     = x.Project.Name,
                Type        = x.Type.ToString()
            })
            .ToList();
```

It complains that `member 'date' is not supported by LINQ`

I am aware that LINQ can't work with dates as it has no concept of how to read and compare them. That is why I specifically asked it to compare the `Year` `Month` and `Day` properties (all are `int`s). What in my query is throwing this exception?

P.S. `EventViewModel.Date` is a `String`

Comment: This is LINQ To Entities which means that your query will have to be translated to SQL in the end. Check the answers on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11663523/using-built-in-sql-functions-in-a-linq-query

Comment: What do you mean LINQ can't work with dates? LINQ absolutely can. LINQ can work with any type, that's the whole point of Language-Integrated Querying. Are you using a particular framework like LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities?

Comment: @pymaxion SOrry, I meant when dealing with entities and SQL.

Comment: I believe, it is not issue with Date in where clause, issue is in your SELECT. Probably at **x.Date.Date.ToString()**. Try same statement excluding SELECT part.

Comment: @Shashibhushan You are correct, commenting out the `x.Date.Date.ToString()` works. What could be the problem?

Comment: the problem is "member 'date' is not supported by LINQ" and even if you remove the .Date call, the ToString() will fail for the same reason.

Comment: This SELECT statement try to get converted into equivalent SQL and during that parsing it find x.Date.Date UNKNOWN, so it doesn't work.

Comment: if you are looking for a speciffic date cant you just compare ticks? single check between two numbers

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your query so you aren't calling the Date property on DateTime and change your view model.

Define your DateTime properties that you defined as string as DateTime.
Annotate the DateTime properties like this

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? Date{ get; set; }
```

or whatever date format you are using in your UI.

Change your query like this

```
        var startDate = date.Date;
        var endDate = date.Date.AddDays(1);

        return db.Events
        .Where(e =>
            e.BedId == bed
            && e.Date >= startDate
            && e.Date < endDate)
        .Select(x => new EventViewModel()
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Date = x.Date,
            StartTime = x.StartTime,
            EndTime = x.EndTime,
            Planned = x.Planned,
            EngineSN = x.EngineSN,
            Details = x.Details,
            Bed = x.Bed.Name,
            Category = x.Subcategory.Category.Name,
            Subcategory = x.Subcategory.Name,
            Project = x.Project.Name,
            Type = x.Type.ToString()
        })
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're trying to do is exclude the time portion of the date in your comparison and in your projection. If that's the case, use DbFunctions.

```
.Where(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(e.Date == date))
```

and then

```
Date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ works with Dates as mentioned by others. It is your SELECT that is complaining at `x.Date.Date.ToString()`

Comment: In ToString is method which is not available in SQL, so during parsing it could not find equivalent SQL part. This is my understanding.